# Is it possible to redirect a user to another page without clearing their history of the page using JavaScript & HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect users to a verification page, after the click a button, I want them to back to where they were before being redirected.

The problem I'm having is that the page they were on isn't being stored in their browser history.

I've tried using `window.location.assign` and `window.location.href`.

I'm using Edge as the browser for testing.

Original page:

```
if(x === -1) {
  window.location.assign = "Redirect to Page";
}
```

Redirect to Page:

```
function yes() {
  // attached to a button
  history.go(-1);
}
```

I expect to go back to original page, since many of my pages will send users to the "redirect to page"

I'd truly appreciate any help here, I'm very new to programming and to be honest barely know the difference between php, jQuery.

Excuse me if I've neglected to include important info.

Comment: When you say *" isn't being stored in their browser history"* do you mean when they go back to that page any changes made before the redirection are gone and only the default data/page is showing?

Comment: Yeah basically, their browser history didn't capture the page that did the redirecting. It instead showed whatever page they were at before reaching my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a query parameter representing the page to go back to:

```
window.location = `redirect.html?redirect=${encodeURIComponent(window.location)}`;
```

On `redirect.html`:

```
function yes() {
    window.location = decodeURIComponent(new URL(window.location).search.split("redirect")[1].split("=")[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks so much for your help!

I ended up going with a localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem to store the value of the URL across pages.

Really appreciate your solutions, I've gotta learn more about php and JQuery

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue to connect/disconnect a user. If I'm right, then you should maybe not target the previous page, but a specific page?

I have faced the same issue, and I did a small project example: https://github.com/nicoesiea/authentification
You can have a look and do the same... I guess it should help you to solve your problem. (it is maybe an old project now... And the security is very VERY bad - look at the password in the database, they are even not encrypted...)

BUt the principal is here, you display a login modal popup (or redirect to a page) to query the login/password in order to check in the database if the user is valid or not. Is it what you are looking to do?

Have a nice day,
Regards, Nico

Comment: NOTE: PHP is the code on the server side (before the user can access your page, during its build), the JS (javascript) is the code helping you to make DOM (HTML/CSS) modifications or other kind magic effect on the client side (using the performance machine of your visitor - in the browser)

Comment: Most of the time:
- I'm using PHP to get data from the database and display them in the page.
- I'm using JS with JQuery to add new content on the page or change some CSS classes (add or remove them)